# Which GNU/Linux distributions have good screen magnifier software, either freely available, or preinstalled?

Tags: linux, distributions, accessibility

Which GNU/Linux distributions have good screen magnifier software, either freely available, or pre-installed with the OS?

Being a visually impaired nerd, I'd like to gain experience on as many platforms as possible. I've gotten accustomed to the smooth magnifying experience with the zoom functionality that comes with every Mac, so it would be nice if there were some software package available which gives me comparable results. This would greatly help me to get started with GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard a lot of good things about [Vinux](http://vinuxproject.org/), It is designed with the Visually Impaired community, And i assume that it has the best of the best with the tools you probably need.

In general you can install most of the software you want, on whatever big distro you chose to use, but the above distro has all of that built in, and even the installation is designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GMAG or DynaMag which are magnifiers available for linux, where GMAG has many additional features like:

1. continuous magnification while you work;
2. optionally changes the contrast of the image;
3. run-time configurable

You can download GMAG from [the gnome-mag page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accessibility/Reviews/gnome-mag),
and read more about magnifiers [here](http://www.magnifiers.org/links/Screen_Magnifiers/UNIX_Linux/).

Comment: The magnifiers.org link now forwards to a completely unrelated site.

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 16.04**

---

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

The terminal opens, type

```
apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Go to Ubuntu icon on Top Left corner of desktop

[image]

Click on it and type compiz

[image]

Click on the compiz icon that appers in the window

The following window opens:

[image]

Click on OK

Go to Accebility --> Enhanced Zoom Desktop --> Tick the box

[image]

Click on Enhanced Zoom Desktop

[image]

Click on Zoom In Key --> Disabled

[image]

Tick the box Enabled

[image]

Click on Grab Key Combination

[image]

Press together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

[image]

Click on OK

[image]

Click on Zoom Out Key --> Disabled

[image]

Tick on the box Enabled

[image]

Click on Grab Key Combination

[image]

Press  together

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image]

Click on OK

[image]

Close the window

[image]

From now on

to Zoom In press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

and to Zoom Out press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In compiz you can also use your mouse wheel.  With modifier keys, as an example I use CTRL+ALT+Mouse 4 to zoom in and CTRL+ALT+Mouse 5 to zoom out.

Suffer from low vision and the Ubuntu Unity desktop is the best that I have found thus far.  I spin up a lot of Linux distributions in KVM and look for their settings for visual enhancement.

You can also use unity desktop in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 too.  There is already a Unity variant of Ubuntu 22.04.

Have not tried GMAG or Dynamag as yet.

I work in Cyber Security BTW.